# Kafka Cluster (ZK, BR, BR, BR) in Vagrant can not establish connection

Tags: linux, networking, vagrant, apache-kafka

The issue is that I am not able to send messages via the producer script to any of my broker inside a cluster.

The setup is a single zookeeper server that runs on the ip ( 192.168.10.2:2181) with default settings.

In addition, there are 3 brokers running on (192.168.10.101:9092,192.168.10.102:9092,192.168.10.103:9092).

After spinning up the broker I can see in the zookeeper shell that the 3 broker are connected.

```
vagrant ssh zookeeper-1
kafka/bin/zookeeper-shell.sh 192.168.10.2:2181
ls /brokers/ids
```

**Output:**

> *Connecting to 192.168.10.2:2181 Welcome to ZooKeeper! JLine support is disabled WATCHER:: WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None
>   path:null ls /brokers/ids [3, 2, 1]*

Now I can create the topics with replication:

```
kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper 192.168.10.2:2181 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 1 --topic my-replicated-topic
```

Afterwards I verify that the topic is created:

```
kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper 192.168.10.2:2181 --topic my-replicated-topic
```

**Output:**

> *Topic:my-replicated-topic    PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:
>     Topic: my-replicated-topic  Partition: 0    Leader: 3   Replicas:
>   3,1,2 Isr: 3,1,2*

If I try now to send a message via the producer:

```
kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 192.168.10.101:9092,192.168.10.102:9092,192.168.10.103:9092 --topic my-replicated-topic
```

> *[2017-12-28 13:53:30,530] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -3 could not be established. Broker may not be
>   available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [2017-12-28
>   13:53:30,536] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to
>   node -2 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
>   (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [2017-12-28 13:53:30,539]
>   WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 could
>   not be established. Broker may not be available.
>   (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)*

Same happens if I try to send messages from one of the broker boxes.

I uploaded the Vagrantfile + scripts here so you can reproduce my problem:
https://github.com/0xBADBAC0N/kafka-vagrant-games

I basically googled now for hours and hope that anyone here maybe now how to fix that issue. I guess it is just a config setting that I fail to see.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jwwI agree with you after looking at your suggestions. After still digging into Kafka I found the solution. The broker, even if he should know his own address, needs to be defined in his own settings with '"listeners=PLAINTEXT://"$BROKER_IP":9092"'. This fixed all issues. :)

Answer (score -1):

The broker, even if he should know his own address, needs to be defined in his own settings with '"listeners=PLAINTEXT://"$BROKER_IP":9092"'.

Comment: Please explain the downvote and explain how to make it better if this is not the correct solution. A downvote without any comment is kind of pointless here...